# Call to method in same obj with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope

I’m trying to create an object that will occasionally rebuild a menu depending on user interaction. The way I’m doing it is by cloning new menu items and deleting the old ones. This means I introduce new instances of divs with a certain class which means I have to reload the jQuery affecting said class.

In the example below a click on menu item will result in "TypeError: this.objMethod is not a function".

How can get the jQueryClick method to call objMethod? I assume this is a scope issue, but I can’t figure out how to get the jQuery function to look beyond itself.

```
function myObj(){
    this.jQueryClick = function(){
        $('.menu-item').click(function(){
            this.objMethod();   
        })
    }

    this.objMethod = function(){
        alert('hounds released');
    }

    this.jQueryClick(); // will be called whenever the menu is rebuild
}

newObj = new myObj;
```

If I call objMethod outside with jQuery like this:

```
$('.menu-item').click(function(){
    newObj.objMethod(); 
})
```

It works, but that will only work for the initial menu and not when it’s rebuild.

Comment: Looks like you need to learn how to bind events to dynamic elements (see: [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

Comment: Looks like you're right! A much more elegant solution than integrating the jQuery in the object itself, which I always thought looked messy. Thanks champ :o)

Comment: hey cool. no probs. Sorry my comment (on rereading it) was a bit blunt.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(document).on('click', '.menu-item',callback function)`; instead of that. It will fetch the selector Everytime from the root document object when it rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the context of `this` is different within the click listener...try resolving the scope by saving `this` to a var:

```
var t = this;

t.jQueryClick = function(){
    $('.menu-item').click(function(){
        t.objMethod();   
    })
}

t.objMethod = function(){
    alert('hounds released');
}

t.jQueryClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

For jquery you need to use

```
$(this)
```

in place of

```
this
```

when binding event through jquery.

So when binding using the .click() method you need to use $(this) for it to be able to find the instance of the object clicked.